# Highcharts bar chart force bar to use space

Tags: highcharts

I need to put some highcharts bar charts into a tight space. Therefore, I specify the max of yAxis to be the same as the value of the greatest bar. In some cases, this causes the bar to use all the available space on the chart. In other cases it does not. How can I get it to always use all the available space? In the following jsfiddle, I am setting the max to 13 (and the max in the data is also 13). If changed to 4, then the bar uses all space.

Here is the max:

```
"yAxis": {
  "min": 0,
  "max": 13,
```

and the data:

```
"data": [0, 0, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelWitt/2ksq39g3/2/

Here is the gap:
[image]

When I set the pertinent values to 4, I don't get this gap:[image]

Comment: I am not able to reproduce. When `yAxis.max: 13` the "a" category goes right to the edge of the plot area.

Comment: @wergeld, I added some pics of what I'm seeing.

Comment: Are you seeing that gap in the jsFiddle? What browser are you using?

Comment: @wergeld, I am seeing the gap in Chrome.

Comment: Interesting. I see now if I shrink the display window in jsFiddle beyond some minimum. If I add Deep's endOnTick then it does not occur.

Comment: Yep, that endOnTick setting did it. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `"endOnTick": false,` in yAxis options. For more details see [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.endOnTick)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "global": {
    "useUTC": false,
    "timezoneOffset": -5
  },
  "chart": {
    "type": "bar",
    "height": 200,
    "marginLeft": 110,
    "marginRight": 0,
    "spacingLeft": 0,
    "spacingRight": 0,
    "style": {
      "fontFamily": "Arial",
      "fontSize": 14
    }
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "exporting": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "",
    "style": {
      "display": "none"
    }
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "text": "",
    "style": {
      "display": "none"
    }
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": ["x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c", "d"],
    "labels": {
      "style": {
        "fontFamily": "Arial",
        "fontSize": "14px"
      }
    },
    "title": {
      "text": null
    },
    "minorTickLength": 0,
    "tickLength": 0
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "min": 0,
    "max": 13,
    "labels": {
      //"enabled": false  /*un comment this*/
    },
    "gridLineWidth": 0,
    "minorTickLength": 0,
    "tickLength": 0,
    "endOnTick": false, /*added*/
    "title": {
      "text": null
    }
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "bar": {
      "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": false,
        "align": "left",
        "inside": true,
        "style": {
          "color": "white",
          "fontSize": "12px",
          "fontFamily": "Arial",
          "textShadow": false
        },
        "shadow": false
      }
    }
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "series": [{
    "pointWidth": 22,
    "name": "Medium",
    "color": "#FFC627",
    "data": [0, 0, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```